# Is there any options to customize stroke_bounds? (Rails Prawn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I want to draw borders for all the pages in my PDF. But while using `stroke_bounds`, I can only draw single dark lined borders alone. I couldn't customize anything?

Does anybody have any idea on how to change the style of my `stroke_bounds` borders?

Comment: Doesn't look like you could change style of stroke_bounds http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.10.2/Prawn/Graphics.html#method-i-stroke_bounds . Maybe creating your own method that draws lines on every page after the document is finished would help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dash` in Prawn::Graphics::Dash
http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics/Dash.html

example:

```
pdf.dash 10, :space => 4
pdf.stroke_bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found out that you can use the "stroke_color" function to change this color.

http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics/Color.html#method-i-stroke_color

```
stroke_color "FF0000"
stroke_bounds
```