# Prawn Dash not working properly

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

```
@pdf.dash(space: 10, phase:0)
@pdf.draw_horizontal_line 50, 500, at: 220
```

This draws a horizontal line with no dash, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reading the documentation, it seems you are fogetting the initial `length` parameter. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958262/is-there-any-options-to-customize-stroke-bounds-rails-prawn

Comment: I have also tried using the `length` parameter, to no effect. The line is still solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, our project was using Prawn `0.8.4`, which (it seems) does not support `Prawn::Graphics#Dash` (although the method is present, which is sort of weird). I managed to solve this problem by using the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/henrik/204854